# ob_flush not working on new apache configuration

Tags: php, apache, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, mod-pagespeed

I recently migrated from [Amazon Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) to my own ubuntu 14.04 lts server.  Everything ported smoothly except one page that uses  `ob_flush` and proceeds to do processing.  Here is that block of code:

```
 <?php 
 //put string of page ----> $string
 ob_end_clean();
 header("Connection: close");
 ignore_user_abort(true); // optional
 ob_start();
 echo ($string);
 $size = ob_get_length();
 header("Content-Length: $size");
 ob_end_flush(); // Strange behaviour, will not work
 flush();            // Unless both are called !
 session_write_close(); // Added a line suggested in the comment
 // Do processing here
sleep(10);
//do stuff
echo "something";
```

I'm expecting the contents of $string to print, instead the contents of $string, and then "something" print.  In this snippet, "something" would still print.   I've disabling mod_pagespeed (which is currently enabled), and made sure gzip, and buffer output were set to off.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/jakesyl/daaaa09feefbbd68af78) is my `php.ini` file (I have it offsite because it's unabridged and possible not relevant to the question).  I also have a suspicion this may have to do with my apache configuration file which you can see [Here](https://gist.github.com/jakesyl/7521b62d05a129443de6).  Finally, if this has anything to do with my issue, [here is a link](https://gist.github.com/jakesyl/7db684f6fa528d2500fa) to my pagespeed configuration.  When I call the function the error log shows no errors, additionally I have root access to the server.  Thank you for helping me fix this issue!

Jake Sylvestre

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are confusing  ob_get_contents and ob_end_flush see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php.

Comment: So your saying I have to *echo* call ob_get_contents(), then ob_end_flush?